# Simulate Pressing Buttons On Keyboard With VBS (I need to force press "/")

Tags: vbscript

I need help force pressing the key "/" on the user's keyboard with VBS, however I can't seem to find anything to indicate whether this is possible or not. My code so far:

```
WScript.sleep 900
set wShell = createObject("wscript.shell")
wShell.sendKeys ">>>Activating Core Statistics {ENTER}"
```

I want it to sendKeys "{/}" or something if that were a command. If it's not possible, please let me know. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script opens notepad and forces the "/" key.

```
  WScript.sleep 900
set wShell = createObject("wscript.shell")
wShell.run "notepad.exe"
Wscript.Sleep 500
wShell.sendKeys "/"
Wscript.Sleep 500
wShell.SendKeys "~"
```

Tell me if it works.